# Group concat all child ids against parent row using query in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Having records in table as below, And we can add record as endless hierarchy

```
-----------------------------------------
| id | name                  | parent_id |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | Income                | NULL      |
| 2  | Bank Account Interest | 1         |
| 3  | FD Interest           | 1         |
| 4  | Personal Account      | 2         |
| 5  | Salary Account        | 2         |
| 6  | Expense               | NULL      |
| 7  | Daily Need Expense    | 6         |
| 8  | Mobile Expense        | 6         |
| 9  | Vehicle Expense       | 6         |
| 10 | vehicle InsuranceRenew| 9         |
| 11 | Father FD             | 3         |
------------------------------------------
```

Need Output as below if parent_id is null,

```
------------------------------------------
| id | name                  | child_ids |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | Income                | 2,3,4,5,11|
| 2  | Expense               | 7,8,9,10  |
------------------------------------------
```

Need Output as below if parent_id = 2,

```
------------------------------------------
| id | name                  | child_ids |
------------------------------------------
| 2  | Bank Account Interest | 4,5,11    |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome. Please help us to help by following these steps https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may want to do it with recursive CTE (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) and a GROUP_CONCAT (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) most likely.

Comment: I would advise **not** using or constructing comma-separated lists - they are a breach of the [1st Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF) whereby every datum must be atomic - I don't think this is the case for your `child_id`s!

Comment: @Vérace I think we can assume that this is just about printing out the results. No comma-separated lists will be stored in any table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6i2dwPvg4PqTfxyCTQZoho/0

And your query could look like

```sql
with recursive myCTE (root_id, id, parent_name, parent_id) as (
    # the most basic level, we need to remember the root id and name
    select id as root_id,
           id,
           name as parent_name,
           parent_id
    from myTable
    # you can control which output you need here or at the end (modifying the `from myCTE`
    where parent_id is null
    # or with that
    # where id = 2

    union all
  
    # combine that in recursive way
    select mC.root_id,
           mT.id,
           mC.parent_name,
           mT.parent_id
    from myTable mT
    inner join myCTE mC on mT.parent_id = mC.id
)
select root_id, parent_name, group_concat(id)
from myCTE
where id <> root_id
group by root_id, parent_name;
```

It uses the recursive CTE statements (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) which allows to gather such hierarchical rows together. At the end, the GROUP_CONCAT is used to combine together strings by groups.

Comment: Perfect solution for my query. Thanks @Adam Tokarski